# jquery/ajax load "this" div on click

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a mysql query on my php page that returns all of the results in a div...sort of like this:

```
echo '<div class="results">' . $result . '</div>';
```

When the div "results" is clicked, I want just that div to reload. I'm trying to do this:

```
$(this).load('testratings.php this').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

but obviously the "this" within the .load() is not correct...looking for the syntax here.

Comment: Does `testratings.php` return more than one DIV with this class, but you just want to insert the new value of this DIV?

Comment: @Barmar correct...there are 10 div's that are .results on testratings.php and I just want it to return the one that's clicked

Comment: In that case try `$(this).load('testratings.php .results:eq('+ $('.results').index(this) +')').hide().fadeIn(2000);` this looks for an index based solution.... this will also fail if the new markup rearranges the html....

Comment: If you want it to work then you need to have some unique property associated with the taget

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each DIV a unique ID:

```
echo echo '<div class="results">
           <div class="results_inner" id="results_"' . $resultid++ . '">' . $result
          . '</div></div>';
```

Then use the jQuery:

```
$(".results").on("click", ".results_inner", function() {
    $(this).parent().load('testratings.php #' + this.id).hide().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

You need the nested DIV because `.load()` loads into the contents of the DIV you apply it to, it doesn't replace the DIV. You could use `.replace()`, but then you'll need to write your own callback function, since there's no shorthand for it.

This solution assumes that the `$resultid` counters will be consistent from one call to the next. You could use some other way to assign unique IDs to each result if appropriate.

Comment: This is still loading all of the results into the 1 div

Comment: I don't see how that can be. The code clearly says to load only a specific ID into the DIV. The IDs are properly unique, right?

Comment: Just updated the answer to use event delegation, since the `.results_inner` DIVs will be replaced dynamically. But I don't think that's related to the problem you describe.

Comment: Will try this. Just a question: should id="results_"' $resultid++ . '"> not be id="results_' . $resultid++ . '"> ?

Answer (score 0):

Give the `div` you want to reload an ID and call it like below.

```
$(this).load('testratings.php #ReloadThisDiv').hide().fadeIn(2000);
```